# Particle に (point in time) without a verb

Tags: syntax, particle-に, time

Could the particle に (point in time) be in a sentence that doesn't end on a verb?
For example: 火曜日に日本語の勉強です。

If incorrect, could anyone explain why? Could it be that time-indicator に always needs a verb?

I checked 'A dictionary of basic Japanese grammar'. All the example sentences ended on a verb, except this one: 来年の夏（に）外国旅行をするつもりです。

(source: Makino, S. and Tsutsui, M. (2006). A dictionary of basic Japanese grammar. 55th ed. Tokyo: Japan Times, p. 289, 290).

Comment: +1 for carefully citing a source, but "55th edition"? Really?

Comment: @EddieKal I don't understand what the problem is....

Comment: I am saying: are you sure that book has been revised at least 55 times?

Comment: @EddieKal oh I might have written a typo. Will check later. Thank you for politely and kindly informing me.

Comment: @JulioJ です is the polite form of だ, which is a verb and it's called the 'copula'.

Comment: @EddieKal My copy says "70th printing: August 2014". I guess 'edition' and 'printing' aren't necessarily the same but these figures seem consistent with 55th and 2006.

Comment: @EddieKal I checked, and it's correct - my version is the 55th ed. The first edition was in 1986.

Comment: @user3856370 Thanks! Does your edition have more example sentences?

Comment: Great! Thanks for doublechecking!

Answer (score 4):

A sentence like 火曜日に日本語の勉強です does occur in everyday conversation.

> A: 来週何か予定がありますか。
> B: はい、月曜日にバイトがあります。それから、火曜日に日本語の勉強です。

However, it doesn’t sound quite grammatical. It sounds like something is omitted and です is added in its place to make it sound like a proper, polite sentence.

The casual version sounds more natural.

> A: 来週何か予定ある？
> B: うん、月曜日にバイト。それから、火曜日に日本語の勉強。

This sounds natural because a lot of things are omitted anyways.

When に points to a specific time, it points to a specific time at which some event or action happens. The event or action itself may be expressed with a noun, but you need a verb to say it happens at the referenced time.

> 火曜日に日本語の勉強が**あります**。
>
> 火曜日に日本語の勉強を**します**。

For this reason, a clause that ends with the time-marking に needs to modify a verbal clause.

The sentence from your book is no exception. It should be read this way.

> ［［来年の夏（**に**）外国旅行を**する**］つもり］です。

The に-clause modifies, or is part of, the verbal clause that ends with する, and this whole thing modifies the noun つもり as a "relative" clause.

Comment: So that's idiomatic ungrammaticality?

Comment: I don't see how it's ungrammatical.

Comment: @Nameless - It’s difficult to draw a line, and the line may move over time. As an example, `[い-Adj]-です` was considered ungrammatical earlier. As for this one, I see it on the side beginner to intermediate learners should avoid. By comparison, 火曜日から日本語の勉強です sounds fine. In fact, 日本語の勉強は火曜日からです is also a valid sentence, whereas (x)日本語の勉強は火曜日にです is clearly ungrammatical. The time-から requires a period and a noun alone is enough to represent that period. The time-に, on the other hand, requires a punctual action or event, and this can be expressed only with a verb. The place-で is similar.

Comment: @EddieKal - I see it as 体言止め followed by です as the politeness marker. To me it sounds natural only in a context where someone is reading out items on a schedule, like ７時に朝食です, ８時にロビーに集合です, etc.

Comment: @aguijonazo Do you have a source that says that the time-に requires a punctual action or event? My books aren't that specific unfortunately, but that's what I've concluded as well. I assumed this to be true, so I forgot to ask.

Comment: @Nameless - "Punctual" may not have been a very good word choice. 毎週火曜日に日本語の勉強をしています is of course grammatical, where the verb describes a habitual state. What I meant to say was that whereas から marks one end of something that can be seen as a line, に marks something that can be seen as one point and a verb is required to bind that thing to a specific point on the timeline because a noun itself is "unbound". In the above example, する does that and いる takes care of the subsequent point-to-line, or action-to-state, conversion. This is not possible with 勉強 alone.